# Is there any downside to iterating over a range for more times than is required to generate desired output?

Tags: python, performance, for-loop, range, shuffle

I'm taking a 100 Days of Code in Python, and I'm trying to create a Python password generator by taking in user input for how many letters, numbers, and symbols they'd like in their password.

The program below runs and generates the desired output, **but I know there must be a better way than iterating over the range an arbitrary number of times to generate a fixed-length password.**

```
import random
letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
numbers = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
symbols = ['!', '#', '$', '%', '&', '(', ')', '*', '+']

print("Welcome to the PyPassword Generator!")
nr_letters= int(input('How many letters would you like in your password?: ')) 
nr_symbols = int(input('How many symbols would you like?: '))
nr_numbers = int(input('How many numbers would you like?: '))

password = ""

# Generate unshuffled password

# for i in range(1, (nr_letters + 1)):
#   password += random.choice(letters)
# for i in range(1, (nr_symbols + 1)):
#   password += random.choice(numbers)
# for i in range(1, (nr_numbers +1)):
#   password += random.choice(symbols)
# print(password)

letter_counter = 0
symbol_counter = 0
number_counter = 0

# NOTE: This seems dumb but it works so...

for i in range(0, 100):
  random_int = random.randint(0, 2)
  if random_int == 0 and letter_counter < nr_letters:
    password += random.choice(letters)
    letter_counter += 1
  elif random_int == 1 and symbol_counter < nr_symbols:
    password += random.choice(symbols)
    symbol_counter += 1
  elif random_int == 2 and number_counter < nr_numbers:
    password += random.choice(numbers)
    number_counter += 1

print(password)
```

Is there a cleaner way I can create a shuffled, fixed-length string through a Python for loop?

**For the future, is there a major downside to iterating through a loop more times than it takes to generate the desired output?**

Comment: You might be interested in the `chr()` function.

Comment: The downside of your approach is, that it is not correct. Your code will generate passwords that don't meet the requirements the user specified. Not very often (it will likely slip through manual testing) but it will.

Comment: The biggest downside to iterating more than necessary is that it could take too long.  The second is that it might reduce the randomness of your result.

Comment: WIth [google](https://www.google.com/) you can choose from ~10200 links to 'password generator python' on stackoverflow. I think you can come up with different ideas on your own.

Comment: Why not just generate your unshuffled password then use `random.shuffle`?

Comment: To add to the previous comment, random.shuffle uses the Fisher-Yates algorithm. It's quite simple ([source code](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Lib/random.py)) and much more efficient (and correct) than your current approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for?:

```py
import random
letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
numbers = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
symbols = ['!', '#', '$', '%', '&', '(', ')', '*', '+']

print("Welcome to the PyPassword Generator!")
nr_letters= int(input('How many letters would you like in your password?: ')) 
nr_symbols = int(input('How many symbols would you like?: '))
nr_numbers = int(input('How many numbers would you like?: '))

password = ""

for i in range(1, sum([nr_letters,nr_numbers,nr_symbols])+1):
  if i<= nr_letters:
    password += random.choice(letters)
  elif i > nr_letters and i<=nr_symbols+nr_letters:
    password += random.choice(symbols)
  elif i > nr_symbols+nr_letters:
    password += random.choice(numbers)

password=[x for x in password]
random.shuffle(password)
password="".join(password)
print(password)
```

Basically, instead of iterating through an arbitrary number, it adds up the number of characters required, then it goes through the range, and adding the numbers/symbols/letters when the requirements are met.

The requirements are basic. While below or equal to the number of letters required, add a letter. Then, you go and add the number of letters and symbols together, and say that it has to meet both above the number of letters, and below letters+symbols. Then, if `i` is above letters+symbols, add numbers. That's pretty much the pattern.

The downside is that you will have to shuffle afterwards like I've done above. `password=[x for x in password]` basically turns `password` into a list. Then you shuffle it with `random.shuffle(password)`, and then join it `password="".join(password)`.

It's basically your first commented out iterations bundled up in 1.

Comment: Thanks - that's incredibly helpful.